# Adding days to a date using std.datetime

Tags: date, d

Why are you not allowed to add *days* to a date in std.datetime? You can add months and years, but not days.

Recently I had to calculate a date for Easter Sunday, then I had to calculate related holidays (Ascension, Pentecost, Trinity, Corpus) by adding a certain number of days (39, 10, 7, 4) to the last date.

I ended up using dayOfYear:

```
date.dayOfYear(date.dayOfYear + offset);
```

This worked well, but only because I remained within the same year. What if I have to add 50 days to, say, dec 28?

Is there an easy way of doing this that I have overlooked?

Comment: there used to be a function int weekDay(d_time t); but it's deprecated now see http://dlang.org/phobos/std_date.html you could still use that i think by parsing it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Duration` from `core.time`.
Importing `std.datetime` will import `core.time`, so you can use it directly as follows.

```
import std.stdio, std.datetime;

void main() {
  auto date = Date(2013, 12, 28);
  writefln("%s + %s = %s", date, 10.days(), date + 10.days());
}
```

BTW, `days()` is an alias to `dur!"days"()` which constructs a `Duration` struct.
Check the documentation of `core.time` http://dlang.org/phobos/core_time.html for more information.

Comment: That's even better than what I found.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't read [this article](http://dlang.org/intro-to-datetime.html) on std.datetime yet, then you probably should, as it will probably answer most basic questions that you have for how to use it.

But in general, [`core.time.Duration`](http://dlang.org/phobos/core_time.html#Duration) is what you should be using for adding and subtracting units from any of the time point types in std.datetime (`SysTime`, `DateTime`, `Date`, or `TimeOfDay`). So, you get code like

```
auto date = Date(2012, 12, 21);
date += dur!"days"(50);
```

or

```
auto date = Date(2012, 12, 21);
date += days(50);
```

(The templated `dur` function is the generic way to generate a `Duration`, but it has aliases for each of the units that it supports, so stuff like `seconds(5)` or `22.minutes()` will work as well).

The `add` function exists for `"months"` and `"years"`, because a `Duration` can't hold months or years (because you can't convert between them and smaller units without a specific date), and there needs to be a way to add months or years to a time point. Also, there's the question of what to do when you add or subtract a month or year to/from a date, and the month that it moves to doesn't include that day, so `add` accepts `AllowDayOverflow` in order to control that (which wouldn't be necessary with smaller units).

```
auto d3 = Date(2000, 2, 29);
d3.add!"years"(1);
assert(d3 == Date(2001, 3, 1));

auto d4 = Date(2000, 2, 29);
d4.add!"years"(1, AllowDayOverflow.no);
assert(d4 == Date(2001, 2, 28));
```

But `add` doesn't accept any other units, because you can simply use the normal arithmetic operations with a `Duration`. Also, subtracting two time points will result in a `Duration`.

```
assert(Date(2012, 12, 5) - Date(2002, 11, 17) == dur!"days"(3671));
assert(Date(2012, 12, 5) - dur!"days"(3671) == Date(2002, 11, 17));
```

Unlike `add`, `roll` accepts all of the units in the type rather than just `"months"` and `"years"`, but that's because it's doing a different operation from `+`, and so adding or subtracting a `Duration` won't work (as that already adds or subtracts). Rather `roll` adds to a specific unit without adding to the others.

```
auto d = Date(2010, 1, 1);
d.roll!"days"(33);
assert(d == Date(2010, 1, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use`roll` method:

```
date.roll!"days"(50);
```

Comment: The roll method doesn't affect larger units, such as months or years.

Comment: Then you can use `add`. Don't ask why there are 2 methods.

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier Because `add` and `roll` do different things. `add` exists because `Duration` doesn't work with months or years (because you can't convert between them and smaller units without a specific date). `roll` on the other hand is adding to a specific unit in a way which will cause that field to roll around (without affecting the larger units) when it gets to the max or min for that field, like you might see with a GUI spin control that controls one of a date's fields.

Answer (score 0):

I did overlook it: you can use dayOfGregorianCal:

```
import std.stdio, std.datetime;

void main() {
    auto d = Date(2012, 12, 28); 
    writeln(d);    // 2012-Dec-28
    d.dayOfGregorianCal(d.dayOfGregorianCal + 50); 
    writeln(d);    // 2013-Feb-16
}
```

Comment: That will technically work in the case of days, but adding a `Duration` is how it's intended to work.